# WPF RadMenuItem / Dropdown menu is not working correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, menu, radmenu

Using the same code but different PC make my dropdown menu using `RadMenuItem` is not working correctly, in some PC/laptops it works fine that dropdown to right side of the menu but in some PC/laptops it dropdown to left side of the menu.

Here is the example, showing the submenu in the right side (PC A) :

[image]

and this is showing the submenu in the left side (PC B):

[image]

I check the resolution of both pc it was different PC A (Windows10) is 1600x900 and PC B(Windows8) is 1366x768. But i tried to change PC A to 1366x768 but its still works fine and dropdown to the right side.

What is wrong with this menu? I want to make it right but i don't know what makes this menu not working correctly.

Comment: Does it always have enough space on the right? You can set `DropDownPlacement` property of submenu to force it to always open to one side, I guess.

Comment: @icebat sorry for the late reply, im using old telerik 2011, and i don't think there is a `DropDownPlacement` is there anything similar to it?